# Issue installing Vapid CMS via terminal with command 'npm install -g @vapid/cli'

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, content-management-system, npm-install

I'm a newbie using the terminal and npm and I’m having issues installing Vapid CMS via terminal on Mac.

I tried both with and without sudo but I get error messages on both cases. When I try npm install -g @vapid/cli this is the error I get:
https://ibb.co/MDQhkNL

The given command 'npm install -g @vapid/cli' doesn't work for me, but I assume it might be a problem of permission.

Comment: If you're installing this globally, it wants to write the module to `/usr/local/lib`, which requires admin privileges, so you need to use `sudo npm install -g @vapid/cli`.

Comment: @ChrisWhite thanks! I tried sudo but it still doesn't work and this is what I get https://ibb.co/dgP5q0k

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Getting the same exact issue. Answer below with --unsafe-perm did nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://windowswebdev.io/getting-vapid-up-and-running-on-wsl-ubuntu) which indicates that, if you go for `sudo npm i -g @vapid/cli --unsafe-perm` it should install. I wind up with an error in the installation of `sharp` after that, though; YMMV. Granted, the WWD guy is using WSL and I'm running Ubuntu, so neither of these answers might be pertinent to MacOS, but it might get you a step farther.